# Formatting the output as XML with lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml, pretty-print

My program basically read an input file, makes an lxml.etree from that file, than for example I add a node to the etree and then I want to print it back on a file.
So to write it back on a file I use:

```
et.write('Documents\Write.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

And the output I have is:

```
<Variable Name="one" RefID="two"><Component Type="three"><Value>four</Value></Component></Variable>
```

While I'd like something like:

```
<Variable Name="one" RefID="two">
    <Component Type="three">
        <Value>four</Value>
    </Component> 
</Variable>
```

Where am I mistaken? I've tried many solutions but none seems to work (beautifulsoup, tidy, parser...)

Comment: could it be windows related? If you try opening your output file with the `io` module: `fp=io.open('Documents\Write.xml', 'w', newline='\r\n')
and then`write to `fp` like that `et.write(fp, pretty_print=True)`
(See http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open)

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm trying what you says but what's fp? The file I want to write? Sorry I'm a beginner!

Comment: Just a file pointer representing the file you want to write, yes. `et.write()` can take as input a filename or a open file pointer, like something coming from `io.open` (http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write). You can try `import io` then `et.write(io.open('Documents\Write.xml', 'w', newline='\r\n'), pretty_print=True)`

Comment: Ok so I have done that and I get this error:    TypeError: must be unicode, not str...what should I do?

Comment: what's the stacktrace? what lines are before the TypeError message?

Comment: et.write(fp, pretty_print=True)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1916, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.write (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:51745)
  File "serializer.pxi", line 482, in lxml.etree._tofilelike (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:104825)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 294, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:9383)
  File "serializer.pxi", line 398, in lxml.etree._FilelikeWriter.write (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103857)
TypeError: must be unicode, not str

Comment: and if you try the other way round?
`f=io.open('Documents\Write.xml', 'w', newline='\r\n')` and 
`f.write(lxml.etree.tostring(et, pretty_print=True))`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the standard parser.
Use a custom parser with `remove_blank_text=True`.

```py
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse(self.output_file, parser=parser)
# Do stuff with the tree here
tree.write(your_output_file, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked for me, same answer as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903759/pretty-print-in-lxml-is-failing-when-i-add-tags-to-a-parsed-tree

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, because it is exactly the way it should work.
Could you try this:

```
root = etree.XML( YOUR XML STRING )
print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)

<Variable Name="one" RefID="two">
  <Component Type="three">
    <Value>four</Value>
  </Component>
</Variable>
```

This should generate a formatted string, which you can process yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is how I do. And in that way it works, but it doesn't when I write on a file..I don't know why! Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am also doing exactly that but running into same issue as @JAWE