# dataframe to hierarchical xml

Tags: python, xml, pandas, lxml

> Read csv to dataframe and then convert that to xml using lxml library

This is my first time handling xml and it appears that there is partial success. Any help will be highly appreciated.

CSV File used to create dataframe:

---

```
Parent,Element,Text,Attribute
,TXLife,"
    ",{'Version': '2.25.00'}
TXLife,UserAuthRequest,"
        ",{}
UserAuthRequest,UserLoginName,*****,{}
UserAuthRequest,UserPswd,"
            ",{}
UserPswd,CryptType,None,{}
UserPswd,Pswd,****,{}
TXLife,TXLifeRequest,"
        ",{'PrimaryObjectID': 'Policy_1'}
TXLifeRequest,TransRefGUID,706D67C1-CC4D-11CF-91FB444554540000,{}
TXLifeRequest,TransType,Holding Change,{'tc': '502'}
TXLifeRequest,TransExeDate,2006-11-19,{}
TXLifeRequest,TransExeTime,13:15:33-07:00,{}
TXLifeRequest,ChangeSubType,"
            ",{}
ChangeSubType,ChangeTC,Change Participant,{'tc': '9'}
TXLifeRequest,OLifE,"
            ",{}
OLifE,Holding,"
                ",{'id': 'Policy_1'}
Holding,HoldingTypeCode,Policy,{'tc': '2'}
Holding,Policy,"
                    ",{}
Policy,PolNumber,1234567,{}
Policy,LineOfBusiness,Annuity,{'tc': '2'}
Policy,Annuity,,{}
OLifE,Party,"
                ",{'id': 'Beneficiary_1'}
Party,PartyTypeCode,Organization,{'tc': '2'}
Party,FullName,The Smith Trust,{}
Party,Organization,"
                    ",{}
Organization,OrgForm,Trust,{'tc': '16'}
Organization,DBA,The Smith Trust,{}
OLifE,Relation,"
                ","{'id': 'Relation_1', 'OriginatingObjectID': 'Policy_1', 'RelatedObjectID': 'Beneficiary_1'}"
Relation,OriginatingObjectType,Holding,{'tc': '4'}
Relation,RelatedObjectType,Party,{'tc': '6'}
Relation,RelationRoleCode,Primary Beneficiary,{'tc': '34'}
Relation,BeneficiaryDesignation,Named,{'tc': '1'}
```

---

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import pandas as pd
import json

# Read the csv file
dfc = pd.read_csv('test_data_txlife.csv') .fillna('NA')
# # Remove rows with comments
# dfc = dfc[~dfc['Element'].str.contains("<cyfunction")].fillna('')
dfc['Attribute'] = dfc['Attribute'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("'", '"'))

# Add the root element for xml
root = etree.Element(dfc['Element'][0])
tree = root.getroottree()

for prnt, elem, txt, attr in dfc[['Parent', 'Element', 'Text', 'Attribute']][1:].values:
    # Convert attributes to json (dictionary)
    attrib = json.loads(attr)
    # list(root) = root.getchildren()
    children = [item for item in str(list(root)).split(' ')]
    rootstring = str(root).split(' ')[1]

#     If the parent is root then add the element as child (appaers to work?)
    if prnt == str(root).split(' ')[1]:
        parent = etree.SubElement(root, elem)

    # If the parent is not root but is one of its children then add the elements to the parent
    elif not prnt == rootstring and prnt in children:
        child = etree.SubElement(parent, elem, attrib).text = txt

#     # If the parent is not in root's descendents then add the childern to the parents
    elif not prnt in [str(item).split(' ') for item in root.iterdescendants()]:
        child = etree.SubElement(parent, elem, attrib).text = txt

print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Actual results:

> ```
> <TXLife>
>   <UserAuthRequest>
>     <UserLoginName>*****</UserLoginName>
>     <UserPswd>
>             </UserPswd>
>     <CryptType>None</CryptType>
>     <Pswd>xxxxxx</Pswd>
>   </UserAuthRequest>
>   <TXLifeRequest>
>     <TransRefGUID>706D67C1-CC4D-11CF-91FB444554540000</TransRefGUID>
>     <TransType tc="502">Holding Change</TransType>
>     <TransExeDate>11/19/2006</TransExeDate>
>     <TransExeTime>13:15:33-07:00</TransExeTime>
>     <ChangeSubType>
>             </ChangeSubType>
>     <ChangeTC tc="9">Change Participant</ChangeTC>
>     <OLifE>
>             </OLifE>
>     <Holding id="Policy_1">
>                 </Holding>
>     <HoldingTypeCode tc="2">Policy</HoldingTypeCode>
>     <Policy>
>                     </Policy>
>     <PolNumber>1234567</PolNumber>
>     <LineOfBusiness tc="2">Annuity</LineOfBusiness>
>     <Annuity>NA</Annuity>
>     <Party id="Beneficiary_1">
>                 </Party>
>     <PartyTypeCode tc="2">Organization</PartyTypeCode>
>     <FullName>The Smith Trust</FullName>
>     <Organization>
>                     </Organization>
>     <OrgForm tc="16">Trust</OrgForm>
>     <DBA>The Smith Trust</DBA>
>     <Relation OriginatingObjectID="Policy_1" RelatedObjectID="Beneficiary_1" id="Relation_1">
>                 </Relation>
>     <OriginatingObjectType tc="4">Holding</OriginatingObjectType>
>     <RelatedObjectType tc="6">Party</RelatedObjectType>
>     <RelationRoleCode tc="34">Primary Beneficiary</RelationRoleCode>
>     <BeneficiaryDesignation tc="1">Named</BeneficiaryDesignation>
>   </TXLifeRequest>
> </TXLife>
> ```

Desired Results:

> ```
> <TXLife Version="2.25.00">
>     <UserAuthRequest>
>         <UserLoginName>*****</UserLoginName>
>         <UserPswd>
>             <CryptType>None</CryptType>
>             <Pswd>****</Pswd>
>         </UserPswd>
>     </UserAuthRequest>
>     <TXLifeRequest PrimaryObjectID="Policy_1">
>         <TransRefGUID>706D67C1-CC4D-11CF-91FB444554540000</TransRefGUID>
>         <TransType tc="502">Holding Change</TransType>
>         <TransExeDate>2006-11-19</TransExeDate>
>         <TransExeTime>13:15:33-07:00</TransExeTime>
>         <ChangeSubType>
>             <ChangeTC tc="9">Change Participant</ChangeTC>
>         </ChangeSubType>
>         <OLifE>
>             <Holding id="Policy_1">
>                 <HoldingTypeCode tc="2">Policy</HoldingTypeCode>
>                 <Policy>
>                     <PolNumber>1234567</PolNumber>
>                     <LineOfBusiness tc="2">Annuity</LineOfBusiness>
>                     <Annuity></Annuity>
>                 </Policy>
>             </Holding>
>             <Party id="Beneficiary_1">
>                 <PartyTypeCode tc="2">Organization</PartyTypeCode>
>                 <FullName>The Smith Trust</FullName>
>                 <Organization>
>                     <OrgForm tc="16">Trust</OrgForm>
>                     <DBA>The Smith Trust</DBA>
>                 </Organization>
>             </Party>
>             <Relation id="Relation_1" OriginatingObjectID="Policy_1" RelatedObjectID="Beneficiary_1">
>                 <OriginatingObjectType tc="4">Holding</OriginatingObjectType>
>                 <RelatedObjectType tc="6">Party</RelatedObjectType>
>                 <RelationRoleCode tc="34">Primary Beneficiary</RelationRoleCode>
>                 <BeneficiaryDesignation tc="1">Named</BeneficiaryDesignation>
>             </Relation>
>         </OLifE>
>     </TXLifeRequest>
> </TXLife>
> ```

How can I get the hierarchical results as showsn above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a great start! Thought it would be easiest to go through your code bit-by-bit and explain where it needs tweaking, and suggest some improvements:

### Reading and cleaning the Data

```py
# Read the csv file
dfc = pd.read_csv('test_data_txlife.csv').fillna('NA')
# # Remove rows with comments
# dfc = dfc[~dfc['Element'].str.contains("<cyfunction")].fillna('')
dfc['Attribute'] = dfc['Attribute'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("'", '"'))
```

The `.apply` works fine, but there's also a `.str.replace()` method you can use, which would be a bit neater and clearer (the `.str` lets you treat the values of a column as string types and act on them accordingly).

### Adding the root

```py
# Add the root element for xml
root = etree.Element(dfc['Element'][0])
tree = root.getroottree()
```

This is all good!

### Looping over the rows

```py
for prnt, elem, txt, attr in dfc[['Parent', 'Element', 'Text', 'Attribute']][1:].values:
```

Since you're retrieving all the columns anyway, you don't need to index into `dfc` to select them, so you can take that part out:

```py
for prnt, elem, txt, attr in dfc[1:].values:
```

This works fine, but there are built-in methods for iterating over items in a DataFrame, and we could use `itertuples()`. This returns a `NamedTuple` for each row, which includes the index (basically the row number) as the first item in the tuple, so we need to adjust for that:

```py
for idx, prnt, elem, txt, attr in dfc[1:].itertuples():
```

### Setting up the variables

```py
    # Convert attributes to json (dictionary)
    attrib = json.loads(attr)
    # list(root) = root.getchildren()
    children = [item for item in str(list(root)).split(' ')]
    rootstring = str(root).split(' ')[1][1:].values:
```

It's a good trick to replace the single quotes with double quotes earlier so we can use `json` to turn the attributes into a dictionary.
Each `Element` has a `.tag` attribute which we can use to get the name, which is what we want here:

```py
children = [item.tag for item in root]
rootstring = root.tag
```

`list(root)` or `root.getchildren()` would both give us a list of the child elements of `root`, but we can also loop through them using `for ... in` with `root` like this.

### Adding the element to the tree

```py
#     If the parent is root then add the element as child (appaers to work?)
    if prnt == str(root).split(' ')[1]:
        parent = etree.SubElement(root, elem)

    # If the parent is not root but is one of its children then add the elements to the parent
    elif not prnt == rootstring and prnt in children:
        child = etree.SubElement(parent, elem, attrib).text = txt

#     # If the parent is not in root's descendents then add the childern to the parents
    elif not prnt in [str(item).split(' ') for item in root.iterdescendants()]:
        child = etree.SubElement(parent, elem, attrib).text = txt
```

- `str(root).split(' ')[1]` is exactly what we set `rootstring` to be above, so we can use that instead
- Since we already checked if `prnt == rootstring` in the first `if` statement, if we've reached the first `elif`, we know it can't be equal so we don't need to check it again
- When we're creating the child, we have two assignments at once... which somehow creates the child with its text successfully(!), but it means `child` is set to `text` and not the new `SubElement`. It would be better to do this in two steps.
- When we're looking for the parent, we're currently creating a list of lists (`split()` returns a list), so it won't work. We want the item tag instead.

Making all these changes gives us:

```py
#     If the parent is root then add the element as child (appaers to work?)
    if prnt == rootstring:
        parent = etree.SubElement(root, elem)

    # If the parent is not root but is one of its children then add the elements to the parent
    elif prnt in children:
        child = etree.SubElement(parent, elem, attrib)
        child.text = txt

#     # If the parent is not in root's descendents then add the childern to the parents
    elif not prnt in [item.tag for item in root.iterdescendants()]:
        child = etree.SubElement(parent, elem, attrib)
        child.text = txt
```

But there's a couple of problems here.

The first part (`if` statement) is fine.

In the second part (the first `elif` statement), we check if the parent of the new element is one of root's children. If it is, we add the new element as a child of `parent`. `parent` is definitely *one* of root's children, but we haven't actually checked if it's the *correct* one. It's just the last thing we added to `root`. Fortunately, because our CSV has all the elements in order, this is the correct one, but it would be better to be more explicit with this.

In the third part (second `elif`), it's good to check if `prnt` already exists further down the tree. But currently, if `prnt` doesn't exist, we're jusr adding the element to `parent`, which isn't its actual parent! And if `prnt` *does* exist, we're not adding the element at all (so we'd need an `else` clause here).

### Solution

Thankfully, there's an easy way out: we can use `.find()` to find the `prnt` element, wherever it is in the tree, and then add the new element on there. This makes the whole thing a lot shorter as well!

```py
for idx, prnt, elem, txt, attr in dfc[1:].itertuples():
    # Convert attributes to json (dictionary)
    attrib = json.loads(attr)
    # Find parent element
    if prnt == root.tag:
        parent = root
    else:
        parent = root.find(".//" + prnt)
    child = etree.SubElement(parent, elem, attrib)
    child.text = txt
```

The `.//` in `root.find(".//" + prnt)` means it will search for anywhere in the tree for the matching element tag (read more here: https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath).

---

### Final script

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import pandas as pd
import json

# Read the csv file
dfc = pd.read_csv('test_data_txlife.csv').fillna("NA")
dfc['Attribute'] = dfc['Attribute'].str.replace("'", '"').apply(lambda s: json.loads(s))

# Add the root element for xml
root = etree.Element(dfc['Element'][0], dfc['Attribute'][0])

for idx, prnt, elem, txt, attr in dfc[1:].itertuples():
    # Fix text
    text = txt.strip()
    if not text:
        text = None
    # Find parent element
    if prnt == root.tag:
        parent = root
    else:
        parent = root.find(".//" + prnt)
    # Create element
    child = etree.SubElement(parent, elem, attr)
    child.text = text

xml_string = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode().replace(">NA<", "><")
print(xml_string)
```

I made a couple more changes:

- I moved the `json.loads` bit for the attribute dictionaries up to when we're changing the quotation marks, and just added it on the end using `apply`. We need it there so that the dictionary is ready to go when we create the root element.
- There are some issues with getting the pretty print to work properly, which is what the "Fix text" part is for (see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903759/pretty-print-in-lxml-is-failing-when-i-add-tags-to-a-parsed-tree) for the problem I was having).
- It would be neatest to have `.fillna("")` (filling with an empty string), but if we do that, we end up with `</Annuity>` instead of `<Annuity></Annuity>` (this is legal XML - if you have an element with no text or subelements, you can just do the closing tag). But to get it to come out as we wanted, we need it to have some 'content' so that the opening tag is created. So I left it as `.fillna("NA")` and then right at the end, manually replace that in the output string.

It's also good to be aware that this script makes (at least) four assumptions about the input data:

- That parent elements are created before any of their children (i.e. that they occur further up in the CSV file)
- That element names are unique (or at least, that any duplicate names don't have any children, so that we're never doing `.find()` where there could be more than one match; `.find()` always returns the first match)
- That there aren't any text values of 'NA' that you want to preserve in the final XML (they'll also get removed when we remove the spurious 'NA' text from the `Annuity` element)
- That text consisting only of whitespace doesn't need to be preserved

Comment: Thank you so much for help. learned several new things with this great ressponse.

Comment: You're very welcome!  I quite like working with `pandas` and `etree`, and I enjoyed doing the write-up and seeing how the whole thing simplified as I tweaked bits. I was a bit worried it would be too late for you, as I'd had the question sitting open in my browser for a few days, so I'm glad it's been helpful! 