# How to take a systematic sample of elements from OSM file

Tags: python

> I am trying to take a  systematic sample of elements from a large OSM file , but I am getting "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" error.  Here is the code I am using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  # Use cElementTree or lxml if too slow

OSM_FILE = "chattanooga.osm"  # Replace this with your osm file
SAMPLE_FILE = "sample.osm"

k = 100  # Parameter: take every k-th top level element

def get_element(osm_file, tags=('node', 'way', 'relation')):
    """Yield element if it is the right type of tag
    Reference:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095434/inserting-newlines-in-xml-file-generated-via-xml-etree-elementtree-in-python
    """
    context = iter(ET.iterparse(osm_file, events=('start', 'end')))
    _, root = next(context)
    for event, elem in context:
        if event == 'end' and elem.tag in tags:
            yield elem
            root.clear()


with open(SAMPLE_FILE, 'wb') as output:
    output.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
    output.write('<osm>\n  ')

    # Write every kth top level element
    for i, element in enumerate(get_element(OSM_FILE)):
        if i % k == 0:
            output.write(ET.tostring(element, encoding='utf-8'))

    output.write('</osm>')
```

> And here is the error I am getting

Thank you all

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-349a323b1196> in <module>()
     23 
     24 with open(SAMPLE_FILE, 'wb') as output:
---> 25     output.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
     26     output.write('<osm>\n  ')
     27 

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: String to file not `open(SAMPLE_FILE, 'wb')`. File output is `StringIO` if used string as `file_source`. `"wb"` (b) meaning binary type accepted/returned.

Comment: I changed the "wb" to "w", but now I am getting different error

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-98ccb95b73cf> in <module>()
     29     for i, element in enumerate(get_element(OSM_FILE)):
     30         if i % k == 0:
---> 31             output.write(ET.tostring(element, encoding='utf-8'))
     32 
     33     output.write('</osm>')

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: `ET.tostring(element, encoding='utf-8')` excepted bytearray ! Write file string directly. Don't decode anything, open file with encoding !