# How to fix thiss error when taking a sample of OSM (OpenStreetMap) data?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, openstreetmap

I am trying to take a sample of the OSM file but keep getting stuck with the following error

I have this piece of code below and I keep receiving the following error:

ERROR:

```
    File "<ipython-input-31-e45dfe148a3d>", line 31
    output.write({'</osm>'})
    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

CODE:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  # Use cElementTree or lxml if too slow
    import os
    
    OSM_FILE = os.path.join("/Users/projects/sandiego.osm")  
    
    SAMPLE_FILE = "sample.osm"
    
    
    def get_element(osm_file, tags=('node', 'way', 'relation')):
        """Yield element if it is the right type of tag
        Reference:
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095434/inserting-newlines-in-xml-file-generated-via-xml-etree-elementtree-in-python
        """
        context = ET.iterparse(osm_file, events=('start', 'end'))
        _, root = next(context)
        for event, elem in context:
            if event == 'end' and elem.tag in tags:
                yield elem
                root.clear()
    
    
    with open(SAMPLE_FILE, 'wb') as output:
        output.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
        output.write('<osm>\n  ')
    
        # Write every 10th top level element
        for i, element in enumerate(get_element(OSM_FILE)):
            if i % 50 == 0:
                output.write(str(ET.tostring(element, encoding='UTF-8'))
    
        output.write('</osm>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parentheses on line 29:
output.write(str(ET.tostring(element, encoding='UTF-8'))**)**

Comment: Thank you so much! I am now receiving the following error:

with open(SAMPLE_FILE, 'rb') as output:
----> 4     output.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')

UnsupportedOperation: write

Comment: @coryrobbins  seems like you are opening the file for reading, try open(SAMPLE_FILE, **'w'**).